# Processing video stays black

Tags: processing

I am very new to processing, so pardon me if it is a dumb question.
If have the following code:`

```
import processing.video.*;

Movie myVideo;
int video_width     = 768;
int video_height    = 576;
int video_slice_x   = video_width/2;
int window_width    = 1000;
int window_height   = video_height;
int draw_position_x = 0; 
boolean newFrame  = false;

void setup() {
  myVideo = new Movie(this, "B1.mov");
  size(window_width, window_height, P2D);
  background(0);
  myVideo.loop();
}

void movieEvent(Movie myMovie) {
  myMovie.read();
  newFrame = true;
}

void draw() {
  if (newFrame) {
    loadPixels();
    for (int y=0; y<window_height; y++){
      int setPixelIndex = y*window_width + draw_position_x;
      int getPixelIndex = y*video_width  + video_slice_x;
      pixels[setPixelIndex] = myVideo.pixels[getPixelIndex];
    }
    updatePixels();

    draw_position_x++;
    if (draw_position_x >= window_width) {
      exit();
    }
    newFrame = false;
  }
}`
```

However, I can hear the music playing, but the screen stays black. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put

```
image(myVideo, 0, 0);
```

into `draw()` function and delete `background 0;` from your `setup()`.
Obviously, your video must be into program folder.
Look at https://processing.org/reference/image_.html to use it properly.

So, your code will be something like:

```
import processing.video.*;

Movie myVideo;
int video_width     = 768;
int video_height    = 576;
int video_slice_x   = video_width/2;
int window_width    = 1000;
int window_height   = video_height;
int draw_position_x = 0; 
boolean newFrame  = false;

void setup() {
  myVideo = new Movie(this, "B1.mov");
  size(window_width, window_height, P2D);
  myVideo.loop();
}

void movieEvent(Movie myMovie) {
  myMovie.read();
  newFrame = true;
}

void draw() {
  image(myVideo, 0, 0);
  if (newFrame) {
    loadPixels();
    for (int y=0; y<window_height; y++){
      int setPixelIndex = y*window_width + draw_position_x;
      int getPixelIndex = y*video_width  + video_slice_x;
      pixels[setPixelIndex] = myVideo.pixels[getPixelIndex];
    }
    updatePixels();

    draw_position_x++;
    if (draw_position_x >= window_width) {
      exit();
    }
    newFrame = false;
  }
}
```